# Why is AngularJS $http changing my GET parameters?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, express

I'm doing a simple GET request to a REST service to get a list of users and sorting by username.

If I use jQuery, everything works well:

```
$.getJSON('/api/users', {
    sort: { username: 'asc' }
}, function(users){ 
    console.log(users) 
});
```

And here's the same thing using Angular $resource:

```
var users = $resource('/api/users');
users.query({
    sort: { username: 'asc' }
}, function(users){
    console.log(users);
});
```

You'd assume it would send the data in the same way, but when I log the query in Express, here is how it's received:

```
// jQuery $.getJSON
{ sort: { username: 'asc' } }

// AngularJS $resource
{ sort: '{"username":"asc"}' }
```

Note that my sort object is now a string.

Why is it doing this? Or am I completely misusing $resource?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it breaking smth? Or just would-be-happy-to-know?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this may be the answer: http://victorblog.com/2012/12/20/make-angularjs-http-service-behave-like-jquery-ajax/

> By default, jQuery transmits data using Content-Type:
>   x-www-form-urlencoded and the familiar foo=bar&baz=moe serialization.
>   AngularJS, however, transmits data using Content-Type:
>   application/json and { "foo": "bar", "baz": "moe" } JSON
>   serialization

I'll have to either update my Angular transformRequest or update my Express server.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$http
  .get("/api/users", { sort: { username: 'asc' } })
  .success(function(data){ /* success callback */ });
  .error(function(data){ /* error callback */ });
```

obviously remember to "include" it in your controller:

```
angular.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http){  });
```

---

try this as well:

```
$http({
    url: '/api/users',
    method: 'GET',
    params: { /* your object here */ }
});
```

Comment: Using $http should look like this: $http({
    url: '/api/users',
    method: 'GET',
    params: {
     sort: { username: 'asc' }
    }
   }).success(function(users){
    console.log(users);
   }); And I still get the same query that $resource sends.

Comment: from angularjs docs: 
Shortcut methods are also available. All shortcut methods require passing in the URL, and request data must be passed in for POST/PUT requests.

  $http.get('/someUrl').success(successCallback);

Comment: Using your edited $http, I still get the same req.query in Express that $resource sends. { sort: '{"username":"asc"}' }

Comment: It seems that the two implementations (jquery and angular) are different. Probably angular doesn't like to send objects in get requests. can you try my first example with .post instead?  if that is reasonable for you of course!